# How do I add/mount an additional hdd to my fedora server 28 without losing the data

Tags: linux

I'm a beginner to Linux and I need help on how I can add/mount my 4TB hard drive. Everything I've read online says I need to partition and format the drive but I do not want to lose the files I have in it. What are the steps I can take to mount this to my server and not lose any data? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I ran the command "fdisk -l" and the drive is labeled as /dev/sdb1

Comment: Just came hear to upvote your question, simply for spelling "lose" correctly. I can't remember the last time I saw that...

Comment: What's the output of `blkid /dev/sdb`?

Comment: what kind of filesystems do you have on the disk?  the command Eugen Rieck suggests will tell us that.

Comment: @Darren LOL!..thanks! I was able to mount it with your answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If your hard drive is formatted in a filesystem that your server will natively recognise, you should just be able to create a directory where you want to mount it (e.g. /mnt) and run the command `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`.